# Does blackberry phone (RIM) provide an API to access their bbm (black berry messsnger ) functionality?

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

Does the blackberry phone from RIM provide an API that would let a developer access their bbm message content and send and receive messages through that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do, in a [separate BBM SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/blackberry-messenger.html)

Comment: i need to share text in bbm,i had posted in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538301/programmatically-share-the-text-in-bbm-blackberry ,how can i solve this