# Programmatically share the text in BBM blackberry

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I need to share my text in BBM, i have tried this code

```java
protected void sendBBM() {
    BlackBerryMessenger bbm = BlackBerryMessenger.getInstance();

    int moduleHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_qm_peer");
    ApplicationDescriptor[] apDes = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(moduleHandle);
    try {
        ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launchApplication("net_rim_bb_qm_peer");
    } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

it's going to BBM menu in **simulator**. but, when i run in my 9300 Mobile it's going to catch statement(`Error starting null: null`), and BBM is not opening.

Can anyone provide some solutions to solve this issue?

Comment: did you checked in some Other Device? to confirm this issue?

Comment: hi,thanks for reply i checked but it's not working is there to add any jar files-thanks

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, it is not going to be that easy. To send a message you need to use the BBM SDK. You can read a getting started guide [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/overview_1323631_11.html). I don't want to discourage you but integrating with BBM in BlackBerry Java is not straightforward. Have a look at the samples in the SDK once you download it.

Comment: Hi smith,i have used http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25690/Register_your_app_with_the_BBM_Platform_1387557_11.jsp,and i have imported net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar(BBM SDK 1.3)file but i can't able to run my project.!! -can u help me to do this